# Possible to use Apple Watch to adjust volume of TvOS or Safari on MacOS?

Tags: appletv, airplay, apple-watch, sound-volume, airpods

I want to use the wheel on the Apple Watch to adjust the volume of whatever I'm listening to... it could be

- Air Pods paired to MacOS (iTunes works, but Safari or other apps don't)
- Apple TV speakers
- MacOS speakers on a MacBookPro

How can I use Apple Watch to change the speaker volume in the above situations?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7982869?start=0&tstart=0) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pz3zAEYQMys) might help.

You can change the AirPod volume from the now playing app.

If you're controlling your now playing on your MBP through the watch, the same might apply - otherwise I don't think it's possible at the moment.